# Laravel status is not changing in the code

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project am trying to change the Clinic status based on status recived in URL. The problem is that it is not going to else case.
Following is my code

```
public function deactivate($id , $status)
    {


        $input_data['id'] = $id;
        $clinic = new Clinic;
        $clinc = Clinic::find($id);
        if ($status="deactive") {
            echo "here";
            die();
            $clinc->ClinicPub = "no";
        }
       else if ($status="active")
        {
            echo "ok";
            die();
            $clinc->ClinicPub = "yes"; 
        }
        if($clinc->save()){
            Session::flash('message', 'Clinic Deactivated Sucessfully');
            Session::flash('msgclass', 'alert-success');
        }
        return redirect('clinics');
    }
```

Here if status is `deactive` its going inside that loop and priiting variable here. But the problem is that is status is `active` , it is not going inside `status=active`  case, it is going inside `deactive case`.

I have also printed to check wether recievd status is correct.but is correct and not going inside the loop

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `==` for comparison

```
public function deactivate($id , $status)
    {


        $input_data['id'] = $id;
        $clinic = new Clinic;
        $clinc = Clinic::find($id);
        if ($status=="deactive") {
            $clinc->ClinicPub = "no";
        }
       else if ($status=="active")
        {
            $clinc->ClinicPub = "yes"; 
        }
        if($clinc->save()){
            Session::flash('message', 'Clinic Deactivated Sucessfully');
            Session::flash('msgclass', 'alert-success');
        }
        return redirect('clinics');
    }
```